# Having Cors errors with laravel and nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a test website hosted in digital ocean, i am having trouble configuring nginx properly as i am getting cors errors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.raskoft.com/Soccya_admin/share' from origin 'https://raskoft.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Here is my env part

```
                                                                                                                                                                        
APP_NAME=Soccya
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:rKhOt7oRqNFOXwO1ngdtrMFZjLswDmGZb/6EqTjtZ70=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://raskoft.com
```

Here is my server Block:

```
 HTTP Server Block
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name raskoft.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    return 301 https://raskoft.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS Server Block for raskoft.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name raskoft.com;

    root /var/www/soccia/public;
    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/raskoft.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/raskoft.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/raskoft.com/chain.pem;

    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    # Additional headers
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://raskoft.com";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # PHP-FPM Configuration
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Disabling access to .ht files and other hidden files
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
  # favicon.ico and robots.txt
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    # Custom error pages
    error_page 404 /index.php;
}

# Optional: HTTPS Server Block for www.raskoft.com to redirect to non-www
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.raskoft.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/raskoft.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/raskoft.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/raskoft.com/chain.pem;

    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    # Redirect www to non-www
    return 301 https://raskoft.com$request_uri;
```

I tried adding www. to server name but didn't fix the cors errors.

Comment: `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*.raskoft.com"`